# Use RFID card on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

I am presently working on RFID-based Java application. I am not able to use RFID reader on my Ubuntu 14.04. Can you please let me know if i have to install any packages or any particular cable required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some Python application stuff a year ago - as I remember,  the program reads the device as HIDRAW (Human Interface Device Raw-input). I ran the program from the command line

Here's a code fragment for you :

```
"""
A class to represent an RFID tag.
Reads an RFID tag from the serial port but checks that the port is available.
"""
import sys

class Rfidtag:
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        '''
        initialise the Serial port
        N.B. use ttyAMA0 for GPIO serial port
        \param timeout: (optional)
        '''
        try:
            import serial
        except ImportError:
            print 'No serial port found'
            sys.exit()
        else:
            self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=timeout)

    def read(self):
        '''
        Read a tag from the serial port. 
        '''
        string = self.ser.read(16) # read the full tag id from the reader
        if len(string) != 0:
            string = string[1:11]  # exclude start x0A and stop x0D bytes
        return string
```